# CMPedometer as property, Error code 103

Tags: objective-c, core-motion

I'm building a step manager class, and in my .m file, I've added CMPedometer as a property:

```
@interface WDStepTrackerManager ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CMPedometer *pedometer;
@end
```

I then instantiate it in my init method (I've also tried lazy instantiation -- no effect):

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.pedometer = [[CMPedometer alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Finally, I try to use the pedometer like so:

```
- (void)stepsForTodayWithCompletion:(void(^)(int steps))completion
{
    [self.pedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate:[[NSDate date] midnight] toDate:[NSDate date] withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (pedometerData) {
                    completion([pedometerData.numberOfSteps intValue]);
                }
            });
    }];
}
```

Every time, however, despite approving access to the data, I receive a 103 error and `pedometerData` is `nil`. (If you're wondering about the `midnight` selector on `NSDate`, it's from a category I built which has tons of unit tests and works correctly, as far as I can tell.) Other questions have said making `CMPedometer` a property of your class should stop this from occurring, but I'm still receiving the error despite doing exactly that.

What am I doing wrong? How can I change my (very simple) code to get the steps?

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: @SkylerLauren, An iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that, despite having a strong pointer to my `CMPedometer` instance, I didn't have a strong pointer to my `WDStepTrackerManager` wrapper class. Instantiating this class and storing it in a strong property solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but instead of making it a property i made it an instance variable, so try this instead

```
@implementation WDStepTrackerManager

CMPedometer *pedometer;

- (instancetype)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self)
   {
      pedometer = [[CMPedometer alloc]init];
   }
   return self;
}
```

And use it like this

```
- (void)stepsForTodayWithCompletion:(void(^)(int steps))completion
{
   NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
   NSDate *startOfDate =[calendar startOfDayForDate:[NSDate date]];

   [pedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate:startOfDate toDate:[NSDate date] withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *error) {
        if (pedometerData) {
                completion([pedometerData.numberOfSteps intValue]);
            }
        });
}];
}
```

Comment: -1 The compiler generates an instance variable for a property too.  So either way it's an instance variable.   That's not the problem.